Loop through row and copy paste to another sheet if condition meet
I have 2 sheets - "Current" and "Email".

I want to have a script that reads that row by row on Column A - D.
If Column D = "", then Copy corresponding Column B value and Paste (and override) to "Email" sheet from Cell A1.
And lastly, for those rows identified in Step 2, input text "email sent" in "Current" sheet Column D



Did you try anything  by your own? Then, what do you man by "Paste (and override) to "Email" sheet from Cell A1"? Don't you need to firstly clear the content of that column and only after that to start copying? Would it be better if existing means 10 rows and from first sheet the code must copy only 7, 3 existing to remain there?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Please, try the next code. It uses arrays and working mostly in memory it should be very fast even for large ranges to be processed. It can previously clear A:A column from "Email" sheet or it can be adapted to add the processed array starting after the last existing value:
Sub moveBBValues()
  Dim wsC As Worksheet, wsE As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrFin, i As Long, k As Long
  
  Set wsC = worksheets("Current")
  Set wsE = worksheets("Email")
  
  lastR = wsC.Range("B" & wsC.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'lastr row in B:B column of "Current" sheet
  
  arr = wsC.Range("B2:D" & lastR).Value2 'place the range in an array for faster processing
  
  ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1) 'ReDim the final array for a maximum of possible elements
  
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)       'iterate between the arr elements:
    If arr(i, 3) = "" Then       'if values in D:D is empty:
        k = k + 1                'increment the final array row variable
        arrFin(k, 1) = arr(i, 1) 'place the value from B:B in the final array
        arr(i, 3) = "email sent" 'write the new status in D:D
    End If
  Next i
  
  If k = 0 Then Exit Sub 'no empty cells in D:D
  
  'drop the modified array back in "Current" stheet
  wsC.Range("B2").Resize(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2)).Value2 = arr
  
  'uncomment the next line if you need to previously clear A:A contents
  'wsE.Columns("A").ClearContents
  
  'Drop only the loaded elements of final array, at once:
  wsE.Range("A1").Resize(k, 1).Value2 = arrFin
End Sub

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Life saver, it works so well! thank you so much. FYI, i did try to resolve it on my own to trying out different solutions from this website, attempting to retrofit it to mine. Obviously it didn't work out to the T so hence i'm posting it here. nevertheless i'm really grateful to receive your help. cheers.

@Raymond Glad I could help! But (almost) everybody place a question only if something goes wrong... So, it is good to show some code, even if it does not work, at least, to prove that you made some effort to solve the issue by your own. It is not a must, but most of the people able to help do not even try helping if you do not try proving that you did something to solve your problem... Since the main issue here is learning, you can do it understanding why the code you show did not work and maybe a piece of code optimizing it or replacing with something faster, more elaborate etc...

An alternative with ADO is;
Sub Test()
    Dim adoCN As Object, RS As Object
    Dim myFile As String, strSQL As String
    
    Sheets("Email").Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count) = Empty
    myFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    
    Set adoCN = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    
    adoCN.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    adoCN.Properties("Data Source") = myFile
    adoCN.Properties("Extended Properties") = "Excel 12.0 Macro; HDR=No;"
    adoCN.Open
    
    strSQL = "Select F2 From [Current$] Where F4 Is Null And F2 Is Not Null"
    RS.Open strSQL, adoCN
    
    Sheets("Email").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset RS
        
    strSQL = "Update [Current$] Set F4='email sent' Where F4 Is Null And F2 Is Not Null"
    adoCN.Execute (strSQL)
    
    Set RS = Nothing
    Set adoCN = Nothing
End Sub


Copy and Replace Values

Functionality (Logic)

It clears existing values in the destination column.
If the lookup value is blank and the return value is no error or blank, it replaces the (blank) lookup value with a specified string and copies the return value to the next row of the destination column.
Optionally, it removes the duplicate return values from the destination column.

The Code

It clears existing values in the destination column.
It copies all source lookup values (modified or not) to the source lookup range (returning any (unexpected) formulas as values).
It returns the required values in the destination column.
It displays a message box.

Sub CopyISINsToEmail()
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Copy ISINs To Email"
     
    ' Define constants.

    ' Source
    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "Current"
    Const SRC_TOP_RETURN_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "B2"
    Const SRC_LOOKUP_COLUMN As String = "D"
    Const SRC_REPLACEMENT As String = "email sent"
    ' Destination
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME As String = "Email"
    Const DST_TOP_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "A1"
    ' Other
    Const REMOVE_DUPLICATE_RETURN_VALUES As Boolean = False
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the destination objects and clear existing data.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim dcell As Range: Set dcell = dws.Range(DST_TOP_CELL_ADDRESS)
    dcell.Resize(dws.Rows.Count - dcell.Row + 1).ClearContents
    
    ' Reference the source objects.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_NAME)
    
    Dim slrg As Range, srrg As Range, SourceRowsCount As Long
    
    With sws.Range(SRC_TOP_RETURN_CELL_ADDRESS)
        SourceRowsCount = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, .Column) _
            .End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If SourceRowsCount < 1 Then
            MsgBox "No data found" & vbLf & "in ""'" & sws.Name & "'!" _
                & .Resize(sws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1).Address(0, 0) & """!", _
                vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set srrg = .Resize(SourceRowsCount)
        Set slrg = srrg.EntireRow.Columns(SRC_LOOKUP_COLUMN)
    End With
        
    ' Return the values of the source ranges in arrays.
        
    Dim lData() As Variant, rData() As Variant
    
    If SourceRowsCount = 1 Then
        ReDim lData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): lData(1, 1) = slrg.Value
        ReDim rData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): rData(1, 1) = srrg.Value
    Else
        lData = slrg.Value
        rData = srrg.Value
    End If
    
    ' For each row in the source arrays:
    '  - Check if the lookup value is blank.
    '  - Check if the return value is no error or blank.
    '  - When both conditions are met:
    '     - Write the replacement string to the lookup array.
    '     - Once the number of replacements becomes smaller than the source row,
    '       write the return value to the top (of the return array).
    
    Dim rValue As Variant, lValue As Variant
    Dim sr As Long, ReplacementsCount As Long
    Dim WereConditionsMet As Boolean
    Dim AreValuesValid As Boolean, AreRowsDifferent As Boolean
    
    For sr = 1 To SourceRowsCount
        ' Check if conditions are met.
        lValue = lData(sr, 1)
        If Len(CStr(lValue)) = 0 Then ' is blank
            rValue = rData(sr, 1)
            If Not IsError(rValue) Then ' is no error
                If Len(rValue) > 0 Then ' is not blank
                    WereConditionsMet = True ' never reset
                    AreValuesValid = True ' reset later
                End If
            End If
        End If
        ' Write if conditions are met.
        If AreValuesValid Then
            lData(sr, 1) = SRC_REPLACEMENT
            ReplacementsCount = ReplacementsCount + 1
            If Not AreRowsDifferent Then
                If ReplacementsCount < sr Then
                    AreRowsDifferent = True ' never reset
                End If
            End If
            If AreRowsDifferent Then ' i.e. 'If ReplacementsCount < sr Then'
                rData(ReplacementsCount, 1) = rData(sr, 1) ' write to top
            End If
            AreValuesValid = False ' reset
        End If
    Next sr
    
    ' Check if no conditions were met.
    
    If Not WereConditionsMet Then ' i.e. 'If ReplacementsCount = 0 Then'
        MsgBox "No value pairs meeting the required conditions were found" _
            & vbLf & "in ""'" & sws.Name & "'!" _
            & Union(slrg, srrg).Address(0, 0) & """!", _
            vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Store the number of replacements in a new variable.
    
    Dim ReturnValuesCount As Long: ReturnValuesCount = ReplacementsCount
    ' Note that the number of replacements may be greater than
    ' the number of return values after removing duplicate return values.
    
    ' Optionally, remove duplicates from the top of the return array.
    
    If REMOVE_DUPLICATE_RETURN_VALUES Then
        ' Reset already used variables.
        AreRowsDifferent = False
        ReturnValuesCount = 0
        
        Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        
        Dim rString As String
        
        For sr = 1 To ReplacementsCount
            rString = CStr(rData(sr, 1))
            If Not dict.Exists(rString) Then
                ReturnValuesCount = ReturnValuesCount + 1
                dict(rString) = Empty
                If Not AreRowsDifferent Then
                    If ReturnValuesCount < sr Then
                        AreRowsDifferent = True ' never reset
                    End If
                End If
                If AreRowsDifferent Then
                    rData(ReturnValuesCount, 1) = rData(sr, 1) ' write to top
                End If
            End If
        Next sr
        
    End If
    
    ' Write the values from the arrays to the ranges.
    
    ' Write the values from the lookup array
    ' to the source lookup range.
    slrg.Value = lData
    ' Write the values from (the top of) the return array
    ' to the destination range.
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dcell.Resize(ReturnValuesCount)
    drg.Value = rData
    
    ' Inform.

    Dim Msg As String:
    Msg = "Copied " & ReturnValuesCount _
        & IIf(REMOVE_DUPLICATE_RETURN_VALUES, " distinct ", "") _
        & " value" & IIf(ReturnValuesCount = 1, "", "s") _
        & vbLf & "from ""'" & sws.Name & "'!" & srrg.Address(0, 0) & """" _
        & vbLf & "to ""'" & dws.Name & "'!" & drg.Address(0, 0) & """." _
        & vbLf & vbLf _
        & IIf(ReturnValuesCount = ReplacementsCount, "The corresponding", _
            ReplacementsCount) _
        & " blank cell" & IIf(ReplacementsCount = 1, "", "s") _
        & vbLf & "in ""'" & sws.Name & "'!" & slrg.Address(0, 0) & """" _
        & vbLf & "were populated with """ & SRC_REPLACEMENT & """."

    MsgBox Msg, vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    
End Sub

